# How to properly define a variable in Python that is global across a package?

Tags: python, global-variables, python-import

Having two files `a.py` and `b.py` with the following content works as expected:

```
# a.py

import b

def a_logger(msg):
    print("a logger:", msg)

b.run()

b.set_logger(a_logger)
b.run()
```

```
# b.py

def b_logger(msg):
    print("b logger:", msg)

def set_logger(logf):
    global b_logger
    b_logger = logf

def run():
    b_logger('hello world!')
```

Prints

```
b logger: hello world!
a logger: hello world!
```

Moving `b.py` into a module works as well.
However, when organized as a package as follows it breaks:

```
# aa.py
import bb

def a_logger(msg):
    print("a logger:", msg)

bb.run()

bb.set_logger(a_logger)
bb.run()
```

```
# __init__.py

from .bb import set_logger
from .cc import run
```

```
# bb.py

def _bb_logger(msg):
    print("b logger:", msg)

def set_logger(logf):
    global _bb_logger
    _bb_logger = logf
```

```
# cc.py

from .bb import _bb_logger

def run():
    _bb_logger('hello world!')
```

Prints

```
b logger: hello world!
b logger: hello world!
```

Apparently, `cc.py` keeps its own copy of `_bb_logger`. Why, and how can I get the intended behaviour?

---

Some observations:

- using a class or a list to enclose the function works, so the problem seems to be the reassignment
- moving the `from .bb import _bb_logger` statement into the `run` function works as well

Comment: Put the variable in the modules namespace, no `global` and you are allowed to change it but not reassign it. If you need reassignment, it's better to use a class and a class attribute.

Comment: @KlausD. I verified that reassignment works with a class. Do you have insight into what causes this behaviour?

Comment: @mrupp: `cc` imports a *value*, not a *variable*, despite storing it in a variable of the same name as that in `bb`.  If you want `bb`’s *variable*, say so: `bb._bb_logger`.

Comment: @DavisHerring. Thanks, that likely explains it. Accessing `bb._bb_logger` could be cumbersome notation-wise, and does not work for me ('module bb has no attribute _bb_logger'). I currently work around the problem by using a `class` and `@staticmethod`s.

Comment: @mrupp: Whether it’s cumbersome or not, Python simply doesn’t have shared, unqualified variables.  And I can’t reproduce your error with that approach.